# How to solve errors after yaourt -S code aborted accidentally,

Tags: package-management, yaourt

When I was installing [`code`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/code/) with `yaourt -S code`, something like `ctrl d` was typed accidentally. Then I try to install `yaourt -S code` again:

```
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config --libs-only-l libsecret-1' returned exit status 0 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.14.21-1-MANJARO
gyp ERR! command \"/usr/bin/node\" \"/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"rebuild\"
gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/yaourt-tmp-czxyl/aur-code/src/vscode/node_modules/keytar
gyp ERR! node -v v9.8.0




[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.12
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.12
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.12
    Aborting...
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.12
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.12
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build code.
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.12
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.12
==> Restart building code ? [y/N]
==> -----------------------------
==> n
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you remove the previous builddir?

Comment: @jasonwryan how to remove the previous builddir?

Comment: `rm -r $wherever_you_build`

Comment: @jasonwryan I cannot find the dir where yaourt build : (

Comment: Really? It is printed in your error message: `gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/yaourt-tmp-czxyl/aur-code/src/vscode/node_modules/keytar`